# VS Code Debugger for Java Dropwizard App throws Class not found error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, dropwizard

I have the following dropwizard app: https://github.com/open-metadata/OpenMetadata, which I am trying to run in debug mode in VS Code. I have tried a few setup of my launch.json file including the recommendation from this SO post [How to debug a java dropwizard app using Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004033/how-to-debug-a-java-dropwizard-app-using-visual-studio-code).

My `launch.json` file is configured as show below.

```json
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (Launch)-OpenMetadataApplication<openmetadata-service>",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "mainClass": "org.openmetadata.service.OpenMetadataApplication",
    "classPaths": [
        "path/to/OpenMetadata/openmetadata-dist",
    ],
    "projectName": "openmetadata-service",
    "args": ""
},
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (Attach)",
    "request": "attach",
    "hostName": "localhost",
    "port": 8000
},
```

I have also tried a simpler config specifying just the classpath and the main class and  trying to launch the app directly from the debugger (vs launching it first with the mvn debugger and then attaching to it through VS Code debugger). This yields the same error.

```json
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (Launch)-OpenMetadataApplication<openmetadata-service>",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "mainClass": "org.openmetadata.service.OpenMetadataApplication",
    "classPaths": [
        "/path/to/OpenMetadata/openmetadata-dist",
    ],
    "projectName": "openmetadata-service",
    "args": ""
},
```

When running the debugger I get a `OpenMetadataApplication class not found` error. As comparison I am able to successfully run the app in debug mode using IntelliJ -- see screenshot below for IntelliJ config.

[image]

Comment: What folder do you open as a workspace? Check out the debug [configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options).

Comment: @JialeDu thanks for taking the time to comment. I open the OpenMetadata folder as a workspace.

Comment: Is it useful to modify the cwd in launch.json?

Comment: I tried with out modifying the cwd to the workspace folder but it throws the same error.BTW, the repo is open source, it should be easily reproducible (the error)

Comment: Don't complicated yourself. VSCode is for js,python, etc but not for java. Eclipse or Intellij are made in java for java developers.

Comment: @JRichardsz yep that is what I am doing currently. I was just hoping that someone had been able to run Dropwizard applications in VS Code. I liked VS Code and ideally would lobe to have only 1 IDE.

Comment: Maybe the autocomplete could work, but features like debug it is so complex to implement it vs code of microsoft